# How to configure USB serial port paramters for a Windows program running in Wine?

Tags: usb, serial-port, wine

I have a small CNC machine that's controlled by a custom piece of Windows software over USB, and I'd like to be able to run it from Linux. The software loads up fine under Wine, but it can't see the machine. I think the problem is that I need to set up the USB serial connection with some specific parameters, which are summarized below (full details [here](http://jrkerr.com/lobocnc/software.html)). I've made a symlink from `/dev/ttyUSB0` to `~/.wine/dosdevices/COM5`. How can I make my USB serial port behave in Wine as specified in these instructions?

*copied from the link above*

```
- Change the COM Port Number to COM5 or COM6 (ignore warnings that the port may be in use)
- Change the Receive buffer size from 4096 to 64
- Change the Transmit buffer size from 4096 to 64
- Change the Latency Timer from 16 to 8
```